# Wrap a span element around specific elements and text nodes within a h2 tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to do the following with jQuery so that this:

```
<h2>
    This is a test 
    <span>i</span>
    mag
    <span>i</span>
    nat
    <span>i</span>
    on  
</h2>
```

Becomes this:

```
<h2>
    This is a test 
    <span class="wrap">
       <span>i</span>
       mag
       <span>i</span>
       nat
       <span>i</span>
       on   
    </span>
</h2>
```

So I want the outer span to wrap all the inner spans.

Don't feel this is a duplicate question as I want to just wrap the all the spans and not the text "This is a test".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your update, you could filter the contents of the `h2` element depending on whether `this` is a `span` element or if `this.previousSibling` is a `span` element:

```js
$('h2').contents().filter(function () {
  return $(this).is('span') || $(this.previousSibling).is('span');
}).wrapAll('<span class="wrap" />');
```

```css
.wrap { color: #f00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>
    This is a test 
    <span>i</span>
    mag
    <span>i</span>
    nat
    <span>i</span>
    on  
</h2>
```

Alternatively, you could also filter the elements and text nodes and exclude the text nodes with trimmed text that equals 'This is a test':

```js
$('h2').contents().filter(function () {
  return this.textContent.trim() !== 'This is a test';
}).wrapAll('<span class="wrap" />');
```

```css
.wrap { color: #f00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>
    This is a test 
    <span>i</span>
    mag
    <span>i</span>
    nat
    <span>i</span>
    on  
</h2>
```

You could also just exclude the first text node as well:

```js
$('h2').contents().filter(function () {
  return this !== this.parentElement.firstChild;
}).wrapAll('<span class="wrap" />');
```

```css
.wrap { color: #f00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>
    This is a test 
    <span>i</span>
    mag
    <span>i</span>
    nat
    <span>i</span>
    on  
</h2>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `$.wrapAll()`:

```js
$(function () {
  $("h2 span").wrapAll('<span class="wrap" />');
});
```

```css
.wrap {background: #ccf;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>
  This is a test 
  <span>Test</span>
  <span>Test</span>
  <span>Test</span>   
</h2>
```

Comment: That's wrapped the spans but the word inside each of those spans are now sitting outside of the `wrap` span.

Comment: Sorry my fault, I should've used the real example. I've updated my question. Essentially the inner spans wrap the i's in the word imagination. I want the entire word (along with the inner spans) to be wrapped with an outer span. Can that be done?

Comment: @Rob Er... Okay... Will see if that's possible.